# Passing params to routes, am I retrieving data correctly?

Tags: angular, angular-router

When I pass data to a route, i.e., an Id number, I'm retrieving the data from a separate service storing this data locally after an API call. Is this the correct way to do this [in Angular 8] or am I missing something?

I've had a good google on multiple occasions but no one seems to answer this question head on lol.

Really sorry if there's another post about this somewhere, just can't find it unfortunately for the latest versions of Angular, plenty for older versions however. Thanks in advance and I appreciate all the help!

```js
ngOnInit() {
  // subscribe to the parameters observable
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     // let us assume params is '1' from a clicked component in a list
     // that routes to this component and passes just '1'.#
     // if I then use this to make a service call for my stuff, 
     // is this the correct way? i.e.,
     this.dummyStore = this.dummyService.getStuff(params);
  });
}
```

Comment: The way you're doing things can work fine. You can also use a __resolver__ to pre-fetch the data before the route loads. Check out the routing section of the docs for more info.

Comment: This will work fine as long as you realize that you are subscribing to the params observable so if you change the path programmatically or the user types in a different param in the URL it will call this function again for each change.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which you can receive the params , for path variables you can use the following example

1.{ path: "fruits/:fruit", component: fruitsComponent }

to retrieve the fruit

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.fruit = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("fruit")
}
```

2.for url query params

```
url = /param1=test&id=222&id2=99"


constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.param1 = params['param1'];
});
}
```